# SELECT NOT IN two foreign keys from other table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find a `SELECT` query that returns all of **tableA.tba_id** that are not exists on tableB (note that are two different foreign keys - **tbb_tbAID1** and **tbb_tbAID2** between data.
[You can find DB Model here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7in6.png)

**What I can do so far**
*This only tests one column*

```
SELECT tba_id FROM tableA 
WHERE tba_id NOT IN
  (SELECT tbb_tbAID1 FROM tableB
  WHERE tbb_date > '$date2')
```

I get a MySQL error when trying to test on both foreign keys

> #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

**Query:**

```
SELECT tba_id FROM tableA 
WHERE tba_id NOT IN
  (SELECT tbb_tbAID1,tbb_tbAID2 FROM tableB
  WHERE tbb_date > '$date2')
```

**Try 2:**

```
SELECT tba_id FROM tableA 
WHERE tba_id NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM tableB
    WHERE (tba_id = tbb_tbAID1 OR tba_id = tbb_tbAID2)
  AND tbb_date > '$date2')
```

But gets more results than the first try (that suggests that it's extremely wrongly done)

**Try3:**

```
SELECT tba_id 
FROM tableA 
  JOIN tableB ON tba_id!=tbb_tbAID1 AND tba_is!=tbb_tbAID2 
WHERE tbb_data > '$data'
```

This results on enormous set of data, far away from first method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to do it.

For `NOT IN` (not recommended because you will get unexpected results if your columns are nullable), you should have 2 subqueries as the `a IN (subquery)` requires that the subquery returns a single column:

```
SELECT tba_id FROM tableA 
WHERE tba_id NOT IN
      ( SELECT tbb_tbAID1
        FROM tableB
        WHERE tbb_date > '$date2'
      )
  AND tba_id NOT IN
      ( SELECT tbb_tbAID2
        FROM tableB
        WHERE tbb_date > '$date2'
      ) ;
```

or a `UNION`:

```
SELECT tba_id FROM tableA 
WHERE tba_id NOT IN
      ( SELECT tbb_tbAID1
        FROM tableB
        WHERE tbb_date > '$date2'
      UNION ALL
        SELECT tbb_tbAID2
        FROM tableB
        WHERE tbb_date > '$date2'
      ) ;
```

My favourite is `NOT EXISTS` and seems you got it almost right, in Try2.

```
SELECT tba_id 
FROM tableA
WHERE NOT EXISTS                  -- notice the difference with your query
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM tableB
        WHERE (tba_id = tbb_tbAID1 OR tba_id = tbb_tbAID2)
          AND tbb_date > '$date2'
      ) ;
```

Of course, you could use 2 subqueries as well:

```
SELECT tba_id 
FROM tableA 
WHERE NOT EXISTS  
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM tableB
        WHERE tba_id = tbb_tbAID1
          AND tbb_date > '$date2'
      ) 
  AND NOT EXISTS  
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM tableB
        WHERE tba_id = tbb_tbAID2
          AND tbb_date > '$date2'
      ) ;
```

You could also use `LEFT JOIN` / `IS NULL` check:

```
SELECT tba_id 
FROM tableA
  LEFT JOIN tableB
    ON  (tba_id = tbb_tbAID1 OR tba_id = tbb_tbAID2)
    AND tbb_date > '$date2'
WHERE tbb_date IS NULL ;
```

or:

```
SELECT tba_id 
FROM tableA
  LEFT JOIN tableB AS b1
    ON  tba_id = b1.tbb_tbAID1
    AND b1.tbb_date > '$date2'
  LEFT JOIN tableB AS b2
    ON  tba_id = b2.tbb_tbAID2
    AND b2.tbb_date > '$date2'
WHERE b1.tbb_tbAID1 IS NULL 
  AND b2.tbb_tbAID2 IS NULL ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The actually working query:

```
SELECT tba_id FROM tableA
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE (tba_id = tbb_tbAID1 OR tba_id = tbb_tbAID2) AND tbb_data > '$date')
```

On **Try2**, I deleted the `tba_id` from `WHERE tba_id NOT EXISTS` and worked like a charm. It should be `WHERE NOT EXISTS ...`